# C# Replace string case insensitive

Tags: c#, .net, replace

I would like to replace "fWord" in the string "Input" as case insensitive.

```
while (FilteredWords.Any(Input.Contains))
{
    foreach (string fWord in FilteredWords)
    {
        Input = Input.Replace(fWord, "****");
    }
}
```

(FilteredWords is a list of strings and Input is the string to "clean")
It works, however is case sensitive.
How do I make fWord case insensitive at replacing?

Comment: you can use [regexp.replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: no it's not a duplicate, because I already saw that method did not work to me (still was case sensitive)....

Comment: @user3395421 just stating "it didn't work" doesn't automatically make it not a duplicate.  IT is recommended that you acknowledge the other question and explain **why** it didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the answer from the duplicate question does't help you, here is the code in your case (notice I removed the `while` loop - the condition in it is false if casing is different and also you don't really need it):

```
foreach (string fWord in FilteredWords)
{
    Input = Regex.Replace(Input, fWord, "****", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

For example, the code below

```
string fWord = "abc";
input = "AbC";
input = Regex.Replace(input, fWord, "****", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

produces the value `****`.

Comment: Still does not work properly... I input "abc" and I get "****" but if I input "AbC" I get "AbC"

Comment: What is `fWord` in this case?

Comment: it's from a foreach, as you can see it's selected by a list of strings

Comment: What's the value of the variable?

Comment: the list currently contains only the strings "abc" and "def" because I'm still testing it.

Comment: So check my example above. It's a simplified code that works fine for me.

Comment: OK it worked but how do I select the words from a list of strings? Because if I do that it will not work (still don't know why).

Comment: Remove the `while` loop as it never gets executed. See the full code in the answer.

Comment: nice ;) it worked. you saved my day!